# PHP variable is not passing to another page with GET

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have this while-loop code for returning data from database

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        (some not important lines...)
        echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=<?php echo ".$row['id'].";?>'>remove record</a></div>";
```

and I want to pass id variable by GET to my remove.php

```
<?php
    include '../db.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_query($con, 'DELETE FROM zapisy WHERE id='$id';')
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

but everytime I click on my link it redirects to

```
remove.php?id=<?php%20echo%2042;?> // <?php echo 42;?> without all that mess, id is good
```

leaving that php tags, that I think should not be here, and not passing my variable to another page - first problem; second - php returns

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in .../admin-panel/remove.php on line 5
```

which tells me something is wrong with the mysql spelling nearby variable, but I was looking for answer and nothing. I changed ' ' to " " and opposite, and nothing. Or is it because variable is not getting value passed and its empty?

I would be very thankful if someone could help me or point me the right path, because I'm stuck at this point and I am just beginning with coding.

Comment: Change `echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=<?php echo ".$row['id'].";?>'>remove record</a></div>";` to `echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>";`

Comment: You are using `mysqli` but why you are not using prepared statement; **WHY?** Your sql statement is sql injectable [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @Albzi and also 2x `.`, because there are single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: @execor, you didn't got your answer yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to :

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        (some not important lines...)
?>
        <div><a href='remove.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>'>remove record</a></div>
<?php }
}
```

OR

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            (some not important lines...)
echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up with HTML and PHP.

Modifications required:

1) You have added `echo` twice. It no need as you are already printing the string.

2) Excessive `<?php` and `?>` tags.

```
echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>";
```

Comment: What you did just removed `echo` `echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=<?php ".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>";`

Comment: @Epodax, I apologise that I have posted answer wrong in rush. I have corrected the answer. Please read.

Comment: @Epodax, thanks for it. I will not make any assumptions blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use again `<?php` when you are already in PHP `echo` function.

Change this:

```
echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=<?php echo ".$row['id'].";?>'>remove record</a></div>";
```

to:

```
echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>";
```

And also you are missing 2x `.` (because there are single quotes, not double quotes) and `;`, change this:

```
mysqli_query($con, 'DELETE FROM zapisy WHERE id='$id';')
```

to:

```
mysqli_query($con, 'DELETE FROM zapisy WHERE id='.$id.';');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is because you shouldn't open php tags inside already opened php tags.

It should be like this:

```
echo "<div><a href='remove.php?id=".$row['id']."'>remove record</a></div>";
```

The second error is because you're missing a `;` in your code and mixing up your quotes. Change your query to this.

```
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM zapisy WHERE id='$id'");
```

**Side note:** Since you're using mysqli, you should be using prepared statements.

Here's a quick example:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE FROM zapisy WHERE id=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: and also 2x `.`. It has to be `mysqli_query($con, 'DELETE FROM zapisy WHERE id='.$id.';');`, because there are single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Legionar, I had just edited it to use double quotes when I read your comment though, thanks buddy :)